# C malloc struct implementation

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I am having a problem with the following program. When I try to compile it, it crashes. I guess it's a segmentation fault somewhere in insert function but I just can't figure out where.

```
char *names[HOW_MANY]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
          "Harriet"};
int ages[HOW_MANY]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};

struct person 
{
  char name[40];
  unsigned int age;
  struct person *next;
};

struct person* insert(struct person *people[], char *name, int age) 
{
  struct person *ptr;
  ptr=(struct person * )malloc(sizeof(struct person));
  if(ptr==NULL)
  {
    printf("error");
    return;
  }
  //ptr=ptr->next;
  strcpy(ptr->name,name);
  ptr->age = age;
  ptr->next=NULL;

}

int main() 
{
  struct person *people[HOW_MANY];
  for (int i =0; i<HOW_MANY;i++) 
      insert (people, names[i], ages[i]);

  for(int i=0;i<HOW_MANY;i++)
    printf("%s %d\n", people[i]->name, people[i]->age);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you single-stepped the code with a debugger?  That should tell you what line has the failure.  I note that `insert` never actually puts `ptr` into the `people` array, which I am guessing is the root problem.

Comment: You have conflicting goals in your code.  Having a `next` member makes it appear that you want to have a linked list of people, but you are declaring an array of `struct person` pointers in `main()`.  Are you trying to construct an array or a linked list of people?

Comment: an array of struct person pointers

Comment: If you want to deal with an array inside the `insert()` function, then you'll need to pass the index of the person you want to modify, such as the `i` loop counter variable and set `people[i]` to be equal to your allocated `person` object.

Comment: What compiler warnings are you getting?  You define your function as `struct person* insert(...) ...`, yet you don't actually return a value - you just fall off bottom of the function.

Comment: Do you mean "when I try to run it , it crashes" ?  If the compiler crashes then it would be a compiler bug.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small change that should get you moving forward:

```
void insert(struct person **person_ptr, char *name, int age) 
{                      /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^ one person */
  struct person *ptr;
  ...
  ptr->next=NULL;
  *person_ptr = ptr;   /* send _ptr_ back to the calling code. */
}

int main() 
{
  struct person *people[HOW_MANY];
  for (int i =0; i<HOW_MANY;i++) 
      insert (&people[i], names[i], ages[i]);
           /* ^      ^^^ Just pass the one person you're interested in */
  ...
}
```

Explanation: `**person_ptr` takes the address of a pointer (`&people[i]`).  Then `*person_ptr=...` will change that value.  So the effect is that `insert()` does (in essence) `*&people[i]=ptr;`, which is to say, `people[i]=ptr;`.  You need the `&` and `*` because C passes arguments by value rather than by reference.

Note that there are some other issues with the code.

- If you run out of memory, the caller of `insert()` doesn't know it.  You know it because of the `"error"` printout, but the caller should know it.
- As @eddiem pointed out, you don't need `next` if you are only using arrays.
- `insert()` is declared to return a `struct person*`, but that return value is never assigned or used.  `insert()` could be `void insert()` or (to indicate success or failure) `bool insert()`.

Comment: `return( ptr );` would be a lot easier.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Agreed.  I was trying to stick to the OP's logic as closely as possible, hence the `**`.

Comment: @cxw the function should either return a value, or be declared `void` return type

Comment: @M.M done! ( filler to meet minimum length )